# What is the upgrade path from Cassandra 3.11.13 to 4.1.0?

Tags: cassandra

I Would like to what is the upgrade path from 3.11.13 to which next version I should upgrade to finally be on 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Try it out in a test environment first. But Cassandra 4.0 and 4.1 use similar SSTable formats, so a rolling upgrade from 3.11.13 direct to 4.1.1 should be possible.

Just make sure to run `nodetool upgradesstables` on each node when complete.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bigtable format](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/architecture/overview.html) for SSTables in Cassandra 3.11.13 is [version `-me-`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.14/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L113) (updated in C* 3.11.11 by [CASSANDRA-16619](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16619)).

Cassandra 4.1 (which has [version `-nb-`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L124)) is able to read [SSTable formats as early as `-ma-`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L125) (from C* 3.0.0).

This means that it is possible to upgrade directly from Cassandra 3.11.13 to 4.1. However, our general recommendation is to **always upgrade to the latest minor patch** before upgrading to the next compatible major version to make sure that the nodes have the fixes for known issues.

In your case the *recommended* upgrade path is:

1. Upgrade to the latest minor patch release (C* 3.11.14 at the time of writing).
2. Upgrade to the latest C* 4.1 release (C* 4.1.1 at the time of writing).

As always, make sure you upgrade all SSTables with `nodetool upgradesstables` BEFORE performing a major version upgrade. Cheers!